# How to balance two dynamic table rows height using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two dynamic tables here.Tables rows details comes dynamically.How can i balance two dynamic table rows height using jquery  my fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/2yvj3/14/

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>name1 name2 name3</td>
<td>name1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>name1 name2 name3</td>
<td>name1</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
<th>details1</th>
<th>details2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sadsad</td>
<td>asdsd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>sadsad</td>
<td>asdsd</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your expected behavior not possible for two different dynamic content tables.

Comment: but i need to make it possible :)

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the following css to td and th elements:

```
td,th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/2yvj3/16/)

Comment: this method not suits for me sorry. Row height need to grow dynamically

Comment: Can you explain what you really want to do? I'd be glad to revise my answer.

Comment: if the  left table height increase dynamically with contents then the same height need to increase corresponding right table row

Comment: Show your code to explain how the left table height would increase and how you want the one on the right to increase.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kannankds/2yvj3/14/  my fiddle here  . In this fiddle there are two tables .First table second row height is more than  second table second row height. first table rows heights will be equels to second table rows height and ts needs to change dynamically